# Google reCAPTCHA dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, recaptcha

I am trying to integrate google reCAPTCHA with a registration form for my website. I have found [a solution at CodeProject.](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/884193/Google-ReCaptcha-ASP-net-Control) I have downloaded the dll and added it to the project Reference folder.

Here are some code snippets:

html:

```html
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard2" OnCreatingUser="CreateUserWizard2_CreatingUser" OnCreateUserError="CreateUserWizard2_CreateUserError" oncreateduser="CreateUserWizard2_CreatedUser" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="/Account/MyDashboard.aspx" ContinueButtonStyle-CssClass="btn btn-default col-md-3 btn-search input-password" runat="server" RequireEmail="false" Width="100%" RenderOuterTable="false" QuestionRequiredErrorMessage="false">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep2" runat="server" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <h5 class="text-center">Please complete the following fields to register for an account</h5>
                <br />
                <h5 class="right">Login Details</h5>
                <br/>
                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" class="form-control height-fix" placeholder="EMAIL" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" TextMode="Email" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ForeColor="red" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard2" />

                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" class="form-control height-fix" placeholder="PASSWORD" TextMode="Password"  />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ForeColor="red" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard2" />

                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" class="form-control height-fix" placeholder="REPEAT PASSWORD" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." ForeColor="red" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard2" />
    <cc1:GoogleReCaptcha ID="ctrlGoogleReCaptcha" runat="server" PublicKey="keyinhere" PrivateKey="secretinheree"  />
                <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />

            </ContentTemplate>
            <CustomNavigationTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server" class="btn btn-md btn-sign-in btn-block btn-padding" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="SUBMIT" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard2" />
            </CustomNavigationTemplate>

        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep2" runat="server" AllowReturn="true" />
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

C#:

```
...
using GoogleReCaptcha;

namespace WebOnline
{
    public partial class PublicAccess : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        private NLog.Logger _log = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        protected void CreateUserWizard2_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Validation code block goes in here.
        }

        [Import]
        IUnitOfWork IUnitOfWork;

        private UnitOfWork _UnitOfWork;
        private UnitOfWork UnitOfWork
        {
            get
            {
                if (_UnitOfWork == null)
                {
                    _UnitOfWork = IUnitOfWork as UnitOfWork;
                }
                return _UnitOfWork;
            }
        }
        private MainMenuPages _currentPage;
        public MainMenuPages CurrentPage
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentPage;
            }
            set
            {
                _currentPage = value;
            }
        }

        protected string GetCurrentPageStyle(string pageName)
        {
            if (CurrentPage.ToString() == pageName)
            {
                return "active-main-li";
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the reCAPTCHA to appear in the form, but trying to validate the CAPTCHA is causing problems. The instructions suggest entering the following code

```
if (ctrlGoogleReCaptcha.Validate())
{
   //submit form success
   lblStatus.Text = "Success";
}
else
{
    //captcha challenge failed
    lblStatus.Text = "Captcha Failed!! Please try again!!";
}
```

However my code doesn't like the `ctrlGoogleReCaptcha.Validate()` method. It says that the name doesn't exist in the current context. Have I not sent this through the `runat="server"` though? I'm not sure why it's not finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not declare google Captcha method. Please add below line in `PublicAccess` class.

```
GoogleReCaptcha.GoogleReCaptcha ctrlGoogleReCaptcha = new GoogleReCaptcha.GoogleReCaptcha();
```